# How to search the group by the DisplayName in Microsoft Graph using curl?

Tags: curl, microsoft-graph-api

According to documentation I can use the following to search Group by name:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search="displayName:Test"
```

With the request header: `ConsistencyLevel: eventual`

I'm trying to do this using curl, unfortunately it returns all groups in AD.

```
curl -H Authorization:my_token_here -H ConsistencyLevel:eventual 
     -s https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search="displayName:Test"
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Does your group's name starts with 'Test' or does it contain 'Test'?

Comment: My group name is "Test" exactly

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have tried in graph explore first and its working perfectly , now coming to curl , could you please try by adding count=true in url.

API - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search="displayName:Test"&$count=true](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$search=%22displayName:Test%22&$count=true)